# updating react state when filtering redux props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to react & redux and having a bit of trouble filtering what I am calling insights (articles, case studies, reports). I want to filter by industry, and I cannot get to the point where the state is updating with the filtered insights.

```
InsightsPage.js


const FilterLink = ({
    filter, 
    data,
    children 
}) => {
    return(
        <a href="#"
            onClick={e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                getVisibleInsights(
                    data,
                    filter
                )
            }}
        >{children}
        </a>    
    );
};

const getVisibleInsights = (
    insights,
    filter
) => {
    switch (filter) {
        case 'SHOW_ALL':
            return insights;
        case 'SHOW_AEROSPACE':
            return insights.filter(
                i => i.industry == 'aerospace');    
        case 'SHOW_HEALTHCARE':
            return insights.filter(
                i => i.industry == 'healthcare');   
    }
}


class InsightsPage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const insights = this.props.insightsPageData.insights;
        return(
            <div className="col-md-12">
                <h2>{this.props.insightsPageData.header}</h2>
                <div className="col-md-4">
                    <InsightsList insights={this.props.visibleInsights} />
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-8">
                  {this.props.children}
                </div>
                <p>
                    Show:
                    {' '}
                    <FilterLink filter="SHOW_ALL" data={insights}>All</FilterLink>
                    {' '}
                    <FilterLink filter="SHOW_AEROSPACE" data={insights}>Aerospace</FilterLink>
                    {' '}
                    <FilterLink filter="SHOW_HEALTHCARE" data={insights}>Healthcare</FilterLink>
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

InsightsPage.propTypes = {
    insightsPageData: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        insightsPageData: state.insightsPageData,
        visibilityFilter: state.insightsPageData.visibilityFilter,
        visibleInsights: getVisibleInsights(state.insightsPageData.insights, state.insightsPageData.visibilityFilter )
    }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(InsightsPage);
```

I am initializing my state with the visibilityFilter set to 'SHOW_ALL'

```
initialState.js

export default {
    employeesPageData: {employees: [], page_info:{stats: []}},
    insightsPageData: {insights:[], visibilityFilter: 'SHOW_ALL'},
    newsArticlesPageData: {news_articles:[], page_info:{}},
}
```

So, what is the best way to update the state of my InsightsPage? They all show at the beginning, so my InsightsList is working. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<FilterLinks>` functional component expects 3 props.  You are pushing in the first, but you are not pushing in the prop for data. Amend it to do so as follows:

```
<FilterLink filter="SHOW_AEROSPACE" data={this.props.insightsPageData} updateInsights={this.updatInsights.bind(this)} >Aerospace</FilterLink>

// Where updateInsights is something like:

function updateInsights (updated_insights){
  this.setState({insights: updated_insights});
}
```

You can then modify the onClick to call:

```
this.props.updateInsights(getVisibleInsights(data, filter));
```

Be aware that this approsch ***only sets the local component state of InsightsPage and not your Redux store***.

**To achieve the latter:**

You'd have to use the new state on your reducer. So: dispatch action on click, that action fires a reducer which uses the filtered state. The change will then propogate down the component tree

Comment: Thanks, I had seen you original comment and updated my question to include the data. So, I can call set state in getVisibleInsights?

Comment: So, where would I put  this.setState({ insights: getVisibleInsights(data, filter) });

Comment: That's what I originally thought, but 'this' is undefined.

Comment: I've amended my answer to clarify what I meant

Comment: Thanks. I'm really close but they won't update. I'm getting the filtered insights into the InsightsPage component but I'm guessing that since I've mapped state to props the visibleInsights won't update unless I go through that function??

Comment: I've added another amendment to my answer

Comment: You're welcome! If you have found my answer useful, please  consider up-voting and/or selecting it as the chosen answer.